# Having functional copy of geodatabase in same SQL Server instance?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, administration

Having an Esri Enterprise geodatabase, I want to have a copy of the database in order to make some tests. I have an instance of SQL Server, and I do not want the overhead of installing and maintain another instance of SQL Server. The tests are going to change the data, that is why I should keep the original data available. Moreover, this is a development environment,it would be nice to have a Database copy per developer.

How do you create a copy of an ESRI enterprise geodatabase on the same SQL Instance?

Comment: Possible, yes (each database is standalone), but there's no way to tell what impact the additional load and storage will have on the production instance. Best practice is to use a different server, but this is also much more expensive.

Comment: It is possible, but I would recommend having a separate SQL Server instance as a test environment, as that is common best practice.  Your IT Department should be able to help you get a test environment set up.  Alternatively, if you don't absolutely need to test in an Enterprise GDB, export the data to a File GDB to do your testing.

Comment: @Vince how can I reach that?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "a copy of the database" and what kind of "tests" you need to do.  If you make the copy of the database at the SQL-level it won't work.  ArcGIS hard-codes the database name all over the place within the data itself, and of course you cannot have two databases with the same name on a single SQL Server instance, so a copy with a different name won't work.  If you copy the database using ArcGIS itself, then that would work, but would not be a true database-level copy.  It depends on your needs and the kind of testing you want to do, whether this matters or not.

Comment: @SonofaBeach what considerations should I have when you state "copy of the database using ArcGIS itself"? The idea is that each developer is able to have a copy of the database in order to reproduce bugs.

Comment: It depends on what kind of bugs.  If you want to test issues with reconciling or versioning at a particular point in time or a particular version, then you would need a database level copy.  If you’re not using versioning, or don’t want to replicate particular versioning issues, then an ArcGIS copy of the database would be fine.

Comment: @SonofaBeach the ArcGIS copy will be enough. Is that the proper name (to look for it in the ArcGIS documentation)?

Comment: There are a number of ways to accomplish this newly clarified task.  What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I do not know the official name for the procedure (backup, copy, mirroring, etc...) therefore I cannot find it on the knowledge base of ESRI.